# Typecast error swift

Tags: swift

So I have an json object which I typecast into my required type.

the json is

```
["data": ["key1" : 1, "key2" : 2, "key3" : 3]]
```

when i typecast 'data' to [String : Int], it fails but passes when i typecast to [String: AnyObject]. And when i type cast the anyobject value to Int, it passes. Below is my code.

```
if let results = json["data"] as? [String: Int] {
  print(results) 
  // This does not pass
} else if let results = json["data"] as? [String: AnyObject] {
  for result in results {
    let intObj = result.value as? Int
    print(intObj)
    //This passes and is not nil. Returns the int correct
  }
}
```

Why does this happen. It could be a mistake from my side. But couldn't decide which direction should I look upto.

UPDATE: SOLVED 
The issue was from my side. The json data had a single string value which messed up. Sorry for wasting time!

Comment: which json parser are you using @shob-Z

Comment: Im just using the swift json serialization 

"try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers) as! [String: Any]"

Comment: Try to ask your backend developer which type it has, might be this is a string type value

Comment: If so result.value as? Int should return me nil. Right?

Comment: If you're using Swift 4, I would highly recommend using the new `Codable` & `JSONDecoder` APIs. I cannot reproduce the problem in your question though, please provide a [mcve].

Comment: In your example all values are Ints, the issue is not reproducible. Maybe in your real content one of them is a String. In any case, you already have the solution: cast as Int conditionally while looping over Any or AnyObject values.

Comment: @Moritz MAYBE one of the values is string. I'll check that and post back

Comment: @Moritz You were right. One specific value messed up! Thanks